# iphone app to be released to app store issues

Tags: iphone, app-store, release

So I am trying to release my iphone app. Couple of issues:

1. how do I remove all the appID's i
   created.  I been trying to remove
   them and I can't
2. I created an appid using
   com.[company name].[app name]
   standard.  It does not appear in the
   list of my available apps?!?!?!? 
   Can't understand why. So when I go
   to IOS portal under app id's i see
   it there.  When i launch the
   assistant and it says select an
   existing app id it is not there. 
   Any thoughts why?

Thanks!
Saro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App IDs created in the developer portal are forever.  You can't ever delete them.  You're stuck with them.  It's been that way for several years.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this was that the application must be in ready for distribution state.